# Creating a distribution list outside of outlook in php

Tags: php, outlook

I am trying to create an outlook distribution list with php but I am having a hard time finding any resources or instructions on how to do so. Is it even possible to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If my memory serves me correct, you can create an XML based contact list that you then import into Outlook. My best suggestion would be to export some contacts from outlook, and look at the XML and then recreate that XML structure via PHP and your contacts.

EDIT - it seams that you can create an CSV file and import that as a distribution list.

Comment: You can't export a distribution list as far as I know. The only way to save it (outside of outlook) seems to be in Rich Text Format. It won't let me re-import that back into outlook though to create a new distribution list.

Comment: Can you create an XML file and import that as a distribution list?

Comment: Nope. I'm on Outlook 2007. I've googled it and apparently the only way to do is it have another user send you a distribution list through and outlook email in RTF.